# Program Works in Python 2.7, but not Python 3.3 (Syntax is compatible for both)

Tags: function, python-3.x, python-2.7

So I have the function `integral(function, n=1000, start=0, stop=100)` defined in `nums.py`:

```
def integral(function, n=1000, start=0, stop=100):
    """Returns integral of function from start to stop with 'n' rectangles"""
    increment, num, x = float(stop - start) / n, 0, start
    while x <= stop:
        num += eval(function)
        if x >= stop: break
        x += increment
    return increment * num
```

However, my teacher (for my Programming class) wants us to create a separate program that gets the input using `input()` and then returns it. So, I have:

```
def main():
    from nums import integral # imports the function that I made in my own 'nums' module
    f, n, a, b = get_input()
    result = integral(f, n, a, b)
    msg = "\nIntegration of " + f + " is: " + str(result)
    print(msg)

def get_input():
    f = str(input("Function (in quotes, eg: 'x^2'; use 'x' as the variable): ")).replace('^', '**')
    # The above makes it Python-evaluable and also gets the input in one line
    n = int(input("Numbers of Rectangles (enter as an integer, eg: 1000): "))
    a = int(input("Start-Point (enter as an integer, eg: 0): "))
    b = int(input("End-Point (enter as an integer, eg: 100): "))
    return f, n, a, b

main()
```

When run in Python 2.7, it works fine:

```
>>> 
Function (in quotes, eg: 'x^2'; use 'x' as the variable): 'x**2'
Numbers of Rectangles (enter as an integer, eg: 1000): 1000
Start-Point (enter as an integer, eg: 0): 0
End-Point (enter as an integer, eg: 100): 100

Integration of x**2 is: 333833.5
```

However, in Python 3.3 (which my teacher insists we use), it raises an error in my `integral` function, with the same exact input:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\my_stuff\Google Drive\documents\SCHOOL\Programming\Python\Programming Class\integration.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\my_stuff\Google Drive\documents\SCHOOL\Programming\Python\Programming Class\integration.py", line 8, in main
    result = integral(f, n, a, b)
  File "D:\my_stuff\Google Drive\Modules\nums.py", line 142, in integral
    num += eval(function)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

In addition, `integral` by itself (in Python 3.3) works fine:

```
>>> from nums import integral
>>> integral('x**2')
333833.4999999991
```

Because of that, I believe the fault is in my program for my class... Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're running into is that `input` works differently in Python 2 and Python 3. In Python 3, the `input` function works like the `raw_input` does in Python 2. Python 2's `input` function is equivalent to `eval(input())` in Python 3.

You're getting into trouble because of the quoteation marks you're typing with the formula. When you type `'x**2'` (with the quotes) as your formula when running on Python 2, the text gets `eval`ed in the `input` function and you get a string with no quotation marks as the result. This works.

When you give the same string to Python 3's `input` function, it doesn't do an `eval`, so the quotation marks remain. When you later `eval` the formula as part of your integral calculation, you get the string `x**2` (without any quotation marks) as the result, not the value of `x` squared. This results in an exception when you try the string to `0`.

To fix this, I suggest either using just one version of Python, or putting the following code at the top of your file to get a Python 3 style `input` in both versions:

```
# ensure we have Python 3 semantics from input, even in Python 2
try:
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    pass
```

Then just type in your formula without quotation marks and it should work correctly.