# Python - Write a for loop to display a given number in reverse

Tags: python

How would I have the user input a number and then have the computer spit their number out in reverse?

```
num = int(input("insert a number of your choice "))
for i in
```

That is all I have so far...
I am using 3.3.4

Comment: your question is incomplete!

Comment: what do you mean "in reverse"?

Comment: What is "reverse"? You want the digits of the base-10 representation of the number from the least to the most significant? What should happen to leading zeros?

Comment: I think the answer I posted might be helpful

Answer (score 5):

Here's an answer that spits out a number in reverse, instead of reversing a string, by repeatedly dividing it by 10 and getting the remainder each time:

```py
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

while num > 0:
    num, remainder = divmod(num, 10)
    print remainder,
```

Oh and I didn't read the requirements carefully either! It has to be a **for** loop. Tsk.

```py
from math import ceil, log10

num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

for i in range(int(ceil(math.log10(num)))): # => how many digits in the number
    num, remainder = divmod(num, 10)
    print remainder,
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to make it int and again make it str! Make it straight like this:

```
num = input("insert a number of your choice ")
print (num[::-1])
```

Or, try this using for loop:

```
>>> rev = ''
>>> for i in range(len(num), 0, -1):
...     rev += num[i-1]
>>> print(int(rev))
```

[Best way to loop over a python string backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961499/best-way-to-loop-over-python-string-backward) says the most efficient/recommended way would be:

```
>>> for c in reversed(num):
...     print(c, end='')
```

Comment: upvote for you since I forgot about  the inverse slice operator.

Answer (score 1):

Why make it a number? 'In reverse' implies a string. So don't cast it to int but use it as string instead and just loop over it backwards.

Comment: The "loop" idea I don't like so much (slicing!) but +1 for not ever casting it to an integer in the first place.

Comment: Ah the slicing thing Christian mentions looks a lot better than looping over the characters actually  :)

Answer (score 1):

You've got here a variety of different answers, many of which look similar.

```
for i in str(num)[::-1]: 
    print i
```

This concise variation does a few things worth saying in english, namely:

1. Cast `num` to a string
2. reverse it (with `[::-1]`, an example of *slicing*, a pythonic idiom that I recommend you befriend)
3. finally, loop over the resultant string (since strings are `iterable`, you can loop over them)
4. and print each character.

Almost all the answers use `[::-1]` to reverse the list -- as you read more code, you will see it more places. I recommend reading more about it on S.O. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation).

Comment: Could you please explain this code in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to do your problem for you since you didn't really try to actually solve it or say what you're specifically having a problem with, but:

```
 num = str(input("..."))
 output = [num[-i] for i in range(len(num))]
 print(output)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
output = input("Insert number of your choice: ")[::-1]
print("Your output!: %s" % output)
```

In python 3.x+ input is automatically a string, doing `[::-1]` reverses the order of the string

Comment: he wants to use loop! Also, in Python 2.7, input takes a string too!

Comment: @S.M.AlMamun In python 2.7 doesn't raw_input return a string and input() evals it? Also, I'm not sure he wants to use a loop I think he just wants to reverse the string. Thanks for the input though

Comment: 1. Title says that: Python - Write a for loop to display a given number in reverse
2. Difference can be found in the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783598/program-works-in-python-2-7-but-not-python-3-3-syntax-is-compatible-for-both