# How to reverse a given number in python using just for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, reverse

i did it in while loop but couldn't do it in for loop

my code using while loop :

```
x=int(input("enter a number: "))
i=0
while(x>0):
    remainder=x%10
    i=(i*10)+remainder
    x//=10
print(i)
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290425/python-write-a-for-loop-to-display-a-given-number-in-reverse

Comment: remove `int()` and it will be simpler to reverse

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Write a for loop to display a given number in reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290425/python-write-a-for-loop-to-display-a-given-number-in-reverse)

Answer (score 0):

In your example your using arithmetic, but why not convert to a string to make life easier?

```
x = int(input("enter a number: "))
result = ""
for char in str(x)[::-1]:
  result += char
print(result)
```

Note that `[::-1]` means "iterate backwards" and that if your number ends with zeros, they'll appear at the start of the reversed string. If you want, you can trim them with `lstrip`:

```
print(result.lstrip("0"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `int()` then you will no need loop

```
x = input("enter a number: ")

result = x[::-1]

print(result)
```

You may need `lstrip('0')` to remove `0` when you convert `10` to `01` and you want to skip `0`.

OR convert to `int` after reversing and it removes `0`

```
x = input("enter a number: ")

result = x[::-1]
i = int(result)

print(i)
```

---

Another example - it uses `for`-loop but it still need `str` at start

```
x = input("enter a number: ")

i = 0

for char in reversed(x):
    i = i*10 + int(char)

print(i)
```

---

With `for`-loop you would have to convert `int` to `str` to know how much diggits it has.

`for`-loop is good when you know how many items you have. `while` is better when you don't know how many items you have, or you don't want to work with items one-by-one but skip something, repeate it, etc.

With `for`-loop you could eventually use `iterator`/`generator` which will raise `__StopIter__` at the end of data - but probably this iterator/generator whould have to use `while` for this :)